# Transforming JavaScript decorators to the configured target environment ("node16") is not supported yet

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, esbuild

I am getting this error in my aws serverless nodejs(v16.20) application, when I run this project using serverless offline command `sls offline -s local`.

This error is generating from esbuild. I am posting my ts config below:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
      "alwaysStrict": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "rootDirs": ["src"]
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      ".webpack",
      ".serverless",
      ".esbuild"
    ]
}
```